# Rounded Corner box using CSS with Nifty not Working, help me

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

Im trying to put a rounded rectangle using Nifty technique. But not working help me. My Code is Below

st.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nifty.js"></script>
<link href="niftyCorners.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="niftyPrint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="stm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
if(!NiftyCheck())
    return;
Rounded("div.indian","#377CB1","#9BD1FA");
}
</script> 


</head>



<body>
<div class="indian">
<p>I am an Indian</p>
</body>
</html>
```

stm.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.indian
{
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:18px;
}
```

Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your <div class="indian"> is not closed. This is probably keeping the Javascript from finding the <div> in the DOM.
2. You need to set the "media" for your print stylesheet. The print stylesheet hides all of the work that the Nifty JS does.
3. You are not setting background colors for the page or the "indian" <div>. Without doing this, the effect will not work correctly.
4. I don't think that setting the height of the "indian" <div> is supported when using the Nifty technique.

Correcting these errors, your code works as seen here: http://demo.raleighbuckner.com/so/1277789/

Also, you should probably use the newer version of the Nifty technique found here: http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect.  You are missing a closing DIV:

```
<body>
<div class="indian">
<p>I am an Indian</p>
</div> <!-- This was missing -->
</body>
```

Also, you're using the old version of Nifty.  Try the newer version: http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html